# Why does A(i,j) := <b(i),b(j)>? (Symetric, positive definite matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, machine-learning

Hope you're having a great day.

Well I've been learning about Analytic Geometry in the mml book, but I've found myself stuck the question statement presented in the photo. Why does A(i,j) := <b(i),b(j)>? I'm really confused.

The quote in the text book goes as follows:

"Consider an n-dimensional vector space V with an inner product h·, ·i :
V × V → R (see Definition 3.3) and an ordered basis B = (b1, . . . , bn) of
V . Recall from Section 2.6.1 that any vectors x, y ∈ V can be written as
linear combinations of the basis vectors so that $
\boldsymbol{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_{i} \boldsymbol{b}_{i} \in V$ and
$y=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j} b_{j} \in V$ for suitable ψi
, λj ∈ R. Due to the bilinearity of the
inner product, it holds for all x, y ∈ V that

$\langle\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_{i} \boldsymbol{b}_{i}, \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j} \boldsymbol{b}_{j}\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \psi_{i}\left\langle\boldsymbol{b}_{i}, \boldsymbol{b}_{j}\right\rangle \lambda_{j}=\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}^{\top} \boldsymbol{A} \hat{y}$

where $
A_{i j}:=\left\langle\boldsymbol{b}_{i}, \boldsymbol{b}_{j}\right\rangle
$ and $
\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}
$ are the coordinates of x and y with respect
to the basis B."

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Yeah, just did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just how matrix and vector multiplication works. If you set
$$
\hat x =\begin{pmatrix} \psi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \psi_n \end{pmatrix}
\;\;\;\mathrm{and} \;\;\;
\hat y =\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
you will note that
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \psi_i A_{ij} \lambda_j = \hat x^T A \hat y\; .
$$
So you get
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \psi_i \,\langle \mathbf{b}_i , \mathbf{b}_j\rangle \,\lambda_j = \hat x^T A \hat y
$$
if you set
$$
A_{ij} = \langle \mathbf{b}_i , \mathbf{b}_j\rangle
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the thing that I don't really get is: why when wanting to verify if a matrix is positive symmetric definite etc.. do we just prove that it's symetric and that $\forall \boldsymbol{x} \in V \backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}: \boldsymbol{x}^{\top} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}>0$? And not that the following is true: Aij:=⟨bi,bj⟩? Do we assume automatically that Aij:=⟨bi,bj⟩ or am I missing something?

Comment: $A_{ij} = \langle b_i , b_j \rangle$ is not something we prove, it is something we define in order to be able to represent the bilinear form as the product $\hat x^T A \hat y$ for a given basis of the finite-dimensional vector space $V.$ It then turns out that the positive-definiteness of the bilinear form is equivalent to the positive-definiteness of the matrix, where the positive-definiteness of the matrix is _defined_ as $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} : x^T A x >0.$

Comment: Also make sure you do not mix up elements of $V$ with their coordinates with respect to a given basis. $\forall x\in V\setminus\{0\} : x^TAx >0$ does not necessarily make sense, because an element of $V$ is not necessarily something that can be used in a matrix-vector multiplication. The elements of $V$ can e.g. be polynomials, periodic functions etc. In general, only the _coordinates_ of a vector (with respect to a given basis) can be used in a matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Not all positive definite matrices are constructed as Gram matrices with $A_{i,j}=\langle b_{i}, b_{j} \rangle$.  However, every Gram matrix constructed from linearly independent basis vectors is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: Also probably related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3304649/113873